# MUI Error I am getting while trying to import with Portal

Tags: reactjs, while-loop, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am getting error while importing Portal from mui
import {Portal} from @mui/base/Portal;

import {Portal} from @mui/base/Portal;
getting error in this line
I think mui updated new version of mui/base
plse help by giving a robust solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout for any releases from MUI. [MUI latest releases]: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases

**Try changing the below line**

```
import {Portal} from @mui/base/Portal; to import {Portal} from @mui/base;
```

Hope this helps.